# Android Floating Action Button doesn't get fixed at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I have a fragment which renders a recycleview with an floating action button. The problem is that when the list is empty, the fab keeps on the right top, when the list has few items, the fab keeps below the list but not at the bottom, and it only keeps totally at the bottom when the list fill the screen with items. Could somebody help me please? Bellow is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.juninho.financeapp.activity.FuncionarioActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/funcionario_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_func"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        app:layout_behavior="com.app.juninho.financeapp.utils.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

if the list is empty, fab keeps at the top, which is wrong:
[image: if the list is empty, fab keeps at the top, which is wrong]

if the list has a few items, fab doesn't keep totally at the bottom:
[image: if the list has a few items, fab doesn't keep totally at the bottom]

Here is the correct way, fab is at the bottom:
[image: Here is the correct way, fab is at the bottom]

Using RelativeLayout it seems to work, but its too at the right/bottom corner:
[image: Using RelativeLayout it seems to work, but its too at the right/bottom corner]

Comment: The problem is most probably in this custom class: com.app.juninho.financeapp.utils.ScrollAwareFABBehavior

Comment: Hi BladeCoder! Thanks for your answer! This custom class just hides the fab when scrooling up the list, and shows it when scrooling down. I've tried to remove this but the problem persists...

Comment: Can you just replace the CoordinatorLayout with a Framelayout/RelativeLayout?

Comment: Hi raknahsnura! Well, now it seems to work but it's too much at the corner... I've updated my question with the picture.. What can i do? Is it according to the latest patterns? Will it fit well on the others devices? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should still use a CoordinatorLayout because it's the only layout supporting behaviors and the default FAB behavior will automatically move up the FAB when a Snackbar is displayed. If you use a custom Behavior make sure it at least inherits from the default FAB behavior. For the rest, CoordinatorLayout works like a FrameLayout so you can remove all layout_align* attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `FAB` attribute: `app:layout_behavior="com.app.juninho.financeapp.utils.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"`.

**#.** You don't need to add this with your `FAB`. Just remove this attribute and add attribute `app:layout_anchor="@id/funcionario_recycler_view"` and `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"` to `FAB` to `anchor` it with `RecyclerView`.

**Update your layout as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.juninho.financeapp.activity.FuncionarioActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/funcionario_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_func"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/funcionario_recycler_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**#.** If you want to hide/show `FAB` when scrolling `RecyclerView`, then you can do it `pragmatically` in your java code as below:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.funcionario_recycler_view);
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_func); 

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {
        if (dy > 0 ||dy<0 && fab.isShown())
        {
            fab.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
    {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
        {
            fab.show();
        }

        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }
});
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: The RecyclerView will not move and the FAB should stay at the bottom right of the layout so no anchor is needed.

Comment: Yes you are right. Layout anchor is not necessary here.

Comment: Hi Guys! Unfortunatelly it didn't work. I'm about to give up on it... It keeps the same behavior. I forgot to tell that i'm using this recycleview and this fab with a Fragment wich sets up the recycleview adapter within it's onViewCreate, and i'm not using snackbar. My app has only one activity, wich holds a Navigation Drawer and FrameLayout wich show all my fragment's layout... Is there something else i can do? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you please post your layout that contains drawer layout and post the java class